# how to get exe file's $lastexitcode that kicked from powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

- I am creating a **powershell script** that call a couple of other
  job.
- I want to call `exe` file and get that `exe` file's `$LASTEXITCODE`
  in a script.

> But in my script even if `exe` finished with **error**,
>   `$LASTEXITCODE` is always set `null`.

Please anyone give me advise.

```
. myjob.exe -param1 $param1 -param2 $param
$LASTEXITCODE
```

when I run that `exe` file with CMD,  collect exit code is set `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to bother about any other value apart from 0 in the $LASTEXITCODE. 
Have a validation after the execution of EXE like this:

```
.\myjob.exe -param1 $param1 -param2 $param
If($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "Execution Successful"
} 
else 
{
    Write-Host "Failure in Execution"
}
```

Note: `$LASTEXITCODE` contains the exit code of the last Win32 executable execution which is equivalent to `%ERRORLEVEL%`

Answer (score 0):

If your executable calls other processes then yes, your errors from those won't be passed and you'll always get a zero.

Does this work?

```
. myjob.exe -param1 $param1 -param2 $param 2>&1
$LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: Whats the difference in what OPs question and your answer towards it. Of course $LastExitCode will tell you the success or failure but how he is gonna validate it? What if the variable value is coming as Null? Check the answer what I suggested so that it will handle both the scenarios. Hope it will help you in better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone gave me answer.
I could not find out why my powershell script cannot get exe file's exit code. But I could catch exit code with the code below:

```
$Process=(Start-Process -FilePath "myjob.exe" -ArgumentList @("-param1",$param1,"-param2",$param) -PassThru -Wait)
$Process.ExitCode
```

thanks.